Not able to call postgres stored procedure with UUID[] as parameter
I have a stored procedure.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE rvprficreationadm.copy_questions(IN target_componentid uuid, INOUT source_questionids uuid[], IN createdby uuid, IN is_copied_from_qb boolean, IN createdThrCd varchar)

This procedure is working fine if I call it from the database. But when I call the same procedure using Java through Hibernate it fails with the below error message

ERROR: function rvprficreationadm.copy_questions(uuid, bytea, uuid, boolean, character varying) does not exist

Here is my Java code to call the procedure.
package com.gartner.rvp.rfi.creation.repository.impl;

import com.gartner.rvp.rfi.creation.repository.CopyQuestionProcedure;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.ParameterMode;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Repository
public class CopyQuestionProcedureImpl implements CopyQuestionProcedure {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<UUID> copyQuestions(UUID componentId, List<UUID> targetQuestionIds, UUID userId) {
        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("rvprficreationadm.copy_questions");
        
        // Register the parameters
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, UUID.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, UUID[].class, ParameterMode.INOUT);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, UUID.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(4, Boolean.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(5, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);

        // Set the parameter values
        query.setParameter(1, componentId);
        query.setParameter(2, targetQuestionIds.toArray(UUID[]::new));
        query.setParameter(3, userId);
        query.setParameter(4, false);
        query.setParameter(5, "COPY_QUESTION");

        // Execute the query
        query.execute();

        // Get the result (updated INOUT parameter)
        UUID[] resultArray = (UUID[]) query.getOutputParameterValue(2);
        return List.of(resultArray);
    }
}

This is failing on 2nd parameter because it is considering it as a byte type.
Is there any solution for this? Please let me know.
I tried calling it through List and UUID[] both are failing.

Try setString using concatenated bytea hex escaped for each question ID.Or as an array of that format

I would create a custom PostgreSQL type for UUID arrays, modify the stored procedure to use this custom type, and then use a native SQL query in your Java code to call the procedure, setting the parameters directly.  Try it.

Just a wild idea: for UUID[] a try setting the following array as the parameter: String[] sa = Arrays.stream(a).map(u ->"\\x" + u.toString().replace("-", "")).toArray(String[]::new);
